# How to write a SQL to count total number of occurrences of value in column after group by while taking count as 1 if the group has the value?

Tags: sql, pandas

I have a data with following structure

```
ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
-------------------------
  1         1      Test
  1         1      FAIL
  1         1      FAIL

  1         2      FAIL
  1         2      FAIL
  1         2      FAIL

  2         1      TEST
  2         1      FAIL
```

As title suggests, I want to count occurrence of 'FAIL' in `ColumnC` after grouping by `ColumnA`, and `ColumnB` and while counting the occurrence, I want to count only one 'FAIL' in the group.

For example, if I did the counting for the above example data, the result will be:

```
ColumnA ColumnB count
---------------------------
   1      1       1 (not 2)
   1      2       1 (not 3)
   2      1       1
```

SQL I've made so far:

```
SELECT
    SUM((CASE ColumnC WHEN 'FAIL' THEN 1 WHEN 'TEST' THEN 0 WHEN 'Test' THEN 0 END))
FROM
    table
GROUP BY 
    ColumnA, ColumnB
```

Above query counts every single 'FAIL' (above example gives 4 for 1 in `ColumnA`) in the group but I only want to count only one occurrence in the group. How should I tackle this?

In `pandas`, I could do something like change value by adding sequence to it by using `cumcount` and change the values by adding sequence number then count only 'FAIL1' after a `GROUP BY`.

Is it possible to do it in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
select columnA,
       count(distinct case when columnC = 'Fail' then columnB end)
from t
group by columnA;
```

Or more concisely:

```
select columnA, count(distinct columnB)
from t
where columnC = 'Fail'
group by columnA;
```

Comment: Thank you. I could use this exactly to get the result I posted in the question. I realised later that I actually want columnB in the view as well. So when I include ColumnB in the SELECT I had to include it in GROUP BY clause, so it counts to 1 or 0 because there is only 1 distinct row or nothing. I've updated the question as well to reflect properly on what I want.

Comment: @JeevaBharathi . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different (or more refined question) than ask as a *new* question.  Modifying a question to invalidate answers is impolite.

Comment: Got it. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct columnA,count(ColumnC)
from t
where columnC = 'Fail'
group by columnA,columnB
order by columnA;
```